# Can't connect to postgres with 'pg' gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I have the following code where I'm trying to test a connection to postgres:

```
require 'pg'

conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "puppetdb", "puppetdb", "puppetbdb")
res  = conn.exec('select tablename, tableowner from pg_tables')
```

I get back the error:

> test.rb:3:in `initialize': FATAL:  password authentication failed for
>   user "puppetdb" (PG::ConnectionBad)   from test.rb:3:in`new'     from
>   test.rb:3:in `'

Yet I have a python script with the same credentials that seems to work perfectly:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='puppetdb' user='puppetdb' host='localhost' port='5432' password='puppetdb'")
```

Given the python script I'm wondering if I've entered the credential wrong?

Comment: `localhost` and `172.17.0.1` are not the same

Comment: Yes @C-Otto I'm updating the python script to read localhost. I just tested locally and the python script works with both URLs. As Docker network is being shared to my localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your password (`puppetbdb`):

```
conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432, '', '', "puppetdb", "puppetdb", "puppetdb")
```